# mysql multiple database prioritize innodb buffer pool size

Tags: mysql, innodb

With a mysql instance and multiple databases within that instance is there a way to allocate which database you would like to assign priority to the buffer pool size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can configure MyISAM dedicated key buffers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11627/less-ram-than-index-length-myisam/11714#11714). No such buffer scheme exists with InnoDB.

Usually, it is recommended to assign up to 80% of server RAM to the InnoDB Buffer Pool.

Since you cannot prioritize which database or tables can occupy the InnoDB Buffer Pool, all you can really do is create a buffer large enough to hold all InnoDB data.

See my earlier posts on sizing the InnoDB Buffer Pool

- `Oct 22, 2012` : [How large should be mysql innodb_buffer_pool_size?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size/27341#27341)
- `Oct 22, 2012` : [How much memory do I need for innodb buffer pool?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27471/how-much-memory-do-i-need-for-innodb-buffer-pool/27472#27472) (This was my post on ServerFault that was later migrated to the DBA StackExchange the next day)
- `Apr 14, 2011` : [What are the main differences between InnoDB and MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194)