# What may cause MyISAM index corruption?

Tags: mysql, index, myisam, corruption

I've had an error message telling about index corruption on the .myi file

Reparing the table fixed the issue

This table is accessed with `select` only, so what is likely to corrupt indexes ?

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
 `col1` mediumint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `col2` mediumint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `fk_brand_trans` smallint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `ref_trans` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `col3` smallint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `attribute` smallint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `ref` varchar(25) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `pos` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 KEY `veh` (`col2`,`col1`),
 KEY `trans` (`ref_trans`,`fk_brand_trans`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `brand` (`fk_brand_trans`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

50M rows, 1.8GB data, 1.4GB index

Comment: A gust of wind ...

Answer (score 1):

Since the MyISAM storage engine only caches indexes, reads from `.MYI` files are the norm. If the `.MYI` file of a given MyISAM table never changes, you have to look into external factors.

Just keep in mind that if the index blocks for a MyISAM table are not in the Key Cache, it must be read from disk, then loaded into the Key Cache.

## EXTERNAL FACTOR #1 : Disk

If the disk blocks that hold the `.MYI` file become corrupt, there may be an error reading index blocks. Doing the `REPAIR TABLE` must have written the rebuilt `.MYI` elsewhere on disk.

## EXTERNAL FACTOR #2 : Memory

If the memory chips become defective and parts of the MyISAM Key Cache is in use there, the `.MYI` file could possibly be considered corrupt when reading index blocks. Doing the `REPAIR TABLE` creates a new `.MYI` and is freshly read into the MyISAM Key Cache.

## SUGGESTION

To reduce or eliminate the amount of reads from the `.MYI` file of a MyISAM table, you should look into setting up a dedicated Key Cache just for this table.

Since your table has a 1.4GB `.MYI` file, make a 1.5GB  dedicate key cache for it:

```
USE mydb
SET GLOBAL my_table_keycache.key_buffer_size = 1536 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
CACHE INDEX mydb.my_table INTO my_table_keycache;
LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE my_table_keycache;
```

I have suggested this before

- `Sep 14, 2012` : [Can I partially invalidate the MySQL table cache?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24244/can-i-partially-invalidate-the-mysql-table-cache/24330#24330)
- `Mar 20, 2012` : [optimal table design mysql with primay key and varchar value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15321/optimal-table-design-mysql-with-primay-key-and-varchar-value/15322#15322)
- `Jan 26, 2012` : [Less RAM than Index_length MyISAM](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11627/less-ram-than-index-length-myisam/11714#11714)

Doing this will also let you know quickly if the external factors apply in the future.

Comment: The disk is a Samsung NVMe SSD and the memory is ECC. Yet if this happens again and if the cause is Factor #2, what is the best solution (other than `repair table` which took a while, like running a command or restarting the server) ?

Comment: Math wrong...  Don't set the key buffer to 1.5TB.